# Алгоритм получения дат в временном промежутке

Tags: алгоритм, дата, время

Необходима реализация алгоритма который бы мог выполнить следующее:

Есть две даты: `start_time` , `end_time`

Число определяющее кол-во необходимых дат: `number` (1-90)

Нужно сгенерировать `number` дат примерно равноотдаленных от друг друга в промежутке дат между `start_time` и `end_time`. То насколько сгенерированные даты отдалены от друг друга нужно сделать рандомным но при этом примерно одинаковым.

Пример:

`start_time = '2021-02-26 12:00:00'`,

`end_time = '2021-02-27 01:00:00'`,

`number = 13`

На выходе нужно 13 таймстепмов, к примеру:

```
2021-02-26 12:00:00
2021-02-26 13:25:00
2021-02-26 14:55:00
2021-02-26 15:45:00
2021-02-26 16:25:00
2021-02-26 17:30:00
2021-02-26 18:40:00
2021-02-26 19:35:00
2021-02-26 20:30:00
2021-02-26 21:55:00
2021-02-26 22:45:00
2021-02-26 23:25:00
2021-02-27 00:45:00
```

У меня есть наброски но хотелось бы услышать чужие идеи, возможно будет лучше решение.

Мой вариант: так как `number` фиксированный от 1 до 90, и минимальный отрезок 2ч между стартом и ендом можно заранее написать функцию что отдает массив с кол-во минут для каждых `number` (штук 5-8) и рандомить их. Но я сразу вижу проблему в том что эти числа не могут быть статическими ведь мы заранее не знаем сколько будет промежуток между `start_time`, `end_time`. Можно к примеру считать кол-во минут между концом и началом, делить на `number` и формировать +-1 +-2 +-3 к этому числу, но не очень красиво. Основная задача сгенерировать именно указанное `number` дат, чтобы они все были внутри указаных промежутков и разница между ними не была слишком разной (например где-то пару минут, где то час).

Язык не важен. Спасибо

Comment: `TS(i) = ROUND(TS(0) + (TS(n) - TS(0)) * i / (n-1))`. PS. Количество дат не может быть меньше 2...

Answer (score 0):

Случайный интервал пусть будет иметь длину в промежутке `[1, 1 + v)`, где `v` определяет насколько разными могут быть интервалы. Для пяти интервалов и `v = 2` получим (округление моё):

```
      1.9   1.2   1.8   2.8   2.3
```

Сложим чтобы получились накопительные суммы (круглая сумма - случайность):

```
0     1.9   3.1   4.9   7.7  10
```

Разделим на последний элемент:

```
0     0.19  0.31  0.49  0.77  1
```

Линейно отобразим на интервал дат выраженный в секундах:

```
2021-02-26 12:00:00 -> 1614330000
2021-02-27 01:00:00 -> 1614376800

1614330000 1614338892 1614344508 1614352932 1614366036 1614376800
```

Значения в секундах округлим до ближайшего целого кратного 300 секундам:

```
1614330000 1614339000 1614344400 1614352800 1614366000 1614376800
```

Переведём во временные отметки:

```
2021-02-26 12:00:00
2021-02-26 14:30:00
2021-02-26 16:00:00
2021-02-26 18:20:00
2021-02-26 22:00:00
2021-02-27 01:00:00
```

Ниже пример кода на Питоне, который реализует этот алгоритм. Единственное отличие от примера - из списка удалёно последнее значение:

```
import datetime
import random


def accumulate(seq):
    s = 0
    yield s
    for v in seq:
        s += v
        yield s


def round_to_grid(seq, origin, step):
    return (origin + round((v - origin) / step) * step for v in seq)


def random_dts(start_time, end_time, step_time, rel_variance, n_intervals):
    start = round(start_time.timestamp())
    end = round(end_time.timestamp())
    step = step_time.total_seconds()
    duration = end - start

    points = tuple(accumulate(1 + rel_variance * random.random() for _ in range(n_intervals)))
    tss = tuple(start + p / points[-1] * duration for p in points[:-1])

    return tuple(map(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp, round_to_grid(tss, start, step)))


start_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 26, 12)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 27, 1)
step_time = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

rel_variance = 1
n_intervals = 13

print(start_time, '-', end_time)
print()
for dt in random_dts(start_time, end_time, step_time, rel_variance, n_intervals):
    print(dt)
```

> ```
> $ python random-intervals.py
> 2021-02-26 12:00:00 - 2021-02-27 01:00:00
>
> 2021-02-26 12:00:00
> 2021-02-26 13:05:00
> 2021-02-26 14:00:00
> 2021-02-26 15:05:00
> 2021-02-26 16:15:00
> 2021-02-26 17:00:00
> 2021-02-26 18:10:00
> 2021-02-26 19:25:00
> 2021-02-26 20:10:00
> 2021-02-26 21:25:00
> 2021-02-26 22:05:00
> 2021-02-26 22:50:00
> 2021-02-26 23:50:00
> ```